# Styles missing from pdf when I convert html to pdf in Node JS

Tags: node.js, pdf, html-to-pdf

I'm using a node package called [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to convert HTML to PDF.

I'm able to create the PDF, but the styling part is missing.

Below is my code:

```
var html = fs.readFileSync('./charts.html', 'utf8');

var options = { format: 'A4'};

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./charts.pdf', function(err, res) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
     console.log(res); 
 });
```

How do I get the styling as well?

Comment: Are you using external styles? Did you try inline styles? Does this module support them?

Comment: Its referred like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../assets/css/vendors.min.css">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html-pdf: css and js files do not appear to be processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603847/html-pdf-css-and-js-files-do-not-appear-to-be-processing)

Comment: @Saeed as suggested in the other question I tried giving absolute URLs, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Try to convert a simple example with inline css! I think the problem is external styling!

Comment: @Saeed It's working fine with simple inline css. When complex CSS is used with links to multiple files, it's not working. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot when multiple external CSS files are involved?

Comment: I don't ever do this. But Use a module like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css) to make styles inline, then use **html-pdf** module.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with direct link to .css file. It is temporary but I think it is a good starting point.

css file is under /public/css

```js
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

```html
 <link href="http://localhost:3000/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score -1):

I  have no idea about html-to-pdf but I have used phantom-html-to-pdf
Here I have used Materialize css You can use Bootstrap or whatever u want
I think this Approach is also work for

```
var conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")();
var fs=require("fs");
var resulthtml = "";
resulthtml += '<html>';
resulthtml += '<head>';
resulthtml += '<script src="bower_components/materialize/dist/js/materialize.js"></script>';
resulthtml += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">';
resulthtml += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/materialize/dist/css/materialize.min.css" />';
resulthtml += '</head>';
resulthtml += '<body>';
resulthtml += '<div class="row">';
/* 
       use html body whatever u want

*/
resulthtml += '</div>';
resulthtml += '</body>';
resulthtml += '<html>';
conversion({ html: resulthtml }, function (err, pdf) {

    var output = fs.createWriteStream('sample.pdf');
    console.log(pdf.logs);
    // respond an http request.
    pdf.stream.pipe(output);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with html-pdf. I ended up using inline style tags and it worked out for me.

Comment: How did you solve it using'inline style tags'? Can you show it more clearly in code?

Comment: Please explain why this is a solution. What does your solution do, how does it solve the problem. (It should also have an educational effect on people who find this question because they have a similar problem. )